# How to create new object of one of two child class?

Tags: python, arrays, class, parent-child

I have class **Animal** and two **Child** classes **Fish** and **Bear**

```
class Fish(Animal):

    def __init__(self, x, y, parent_engine):
        self.parent = parent_engine
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.type = 2
        self.image = ''
        self.life = 1


class Bear(Animal):

    def __init__(self, x, y, parent_engine):
        self.parent = parent_engine
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.type = 3
        self.image = ''
        self.life = 1
```

In code i have array of **Animal type** objects named **Field**

```
class Engine:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.field = []
        self.field_size = size
```

I have function **create_actor_child** with input **actor (Animal object)**. This function should creates new **Animal** with **same child class**. I am using if - watching is Parent Bear - spawn Bear, else spawn Fish. But if i will have 10 child it will be hard. I think there should be solution to create new copy of parent class.

```
def create_actors_child(self, actors):  # returns parents back

    sample = actors[0]

    x = sample.x
    y = sample.y

    for actor in actors:
        actor.go_back_event()

    if sample.type == 2:
        self.field.append(bp.Fish(x, y, self))
    else:
        self.field.append(bp.Bear(x, y, self))
```

I need something like `self.field.append(parent_class(actor))`.

**Is there an easy way to do so in Python or do I need to create my own method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from a semantical POV, inheritance describes a "is a" relationship, so (as long as your child classes respect liskov's substitution principle) a fish or bear IS an animal already. Also, creating "new copy of parent class" will actually create new distinct objects which is certainly not what you want.

A better solution is to keep a registery (dict) of child classes (using  `type` as key) and provide a factory function or method, ie:

```
class Animal(object):
    # your code here


    # XXX : Q&D code, missing sanity checks and error handling
    __registry = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, subcls): 
        cls.__registry[subcls.type] = subcls

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, type, x, y, engine):
        return cls.__registry[type](x, y, engine)



class Engine(object):

    def create_actors_child(self, actors):  # returns parents back

        sample = actors[0]

        x = sample.x
        y = sample.y

        for actor in actors:
            actor.go_back_event()

        self.field.append(Animal.create(sample.type, x, y, self))
```

Note that at this point if don't have any other use for `Animal.type` you could as well just use the child class itself directly (and get rid of the registry):

```
    def create_actors_child(self, actors):  # returns parents back

        sample = actors[0]

        x = sample.x
        y = sample.y

        for actor in actors:
            actor.go_back_event()

        samplecls = type(sample)
        self.field.append(samplecls(x, y, self))
```

You may also want to check [the abc module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) for some more evolved features wrt/ subclasses etc.